# Create a Git alias with dynamic argument

Tags: git

If I'm working on a branch, my CL:

```
> my-project git:(my-branch)
```

When I want to push my commits I have to do:

```
> my-project git:(my-branch) git push origin my-branch
```

Is there a way I can create an alias that takes the name of the branch automatically and put it in the original command?

When I type just `git push`, I get the following error: `git push --set-upstream origin my-branch`

Comment: `git push --set-upstream origin` does not look at all like an error message.

Comment: If you've executed the command `git push -u origin` once, subsequent invocations of `git push` should do exactly what you seem to be asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to pass an argument here, since `HEAD` already contains current branch name.

```
git config --global alias.p 'push origin HEAD'
```

then `git p` will push the current branch to its remote counterpart

Comment: In that case, presumably, `@` would do? Indeed, I guess in that sense it is the name of the current branch?

Comment: Yes, `git push origin @` works the same, I tried to remain explicit in an alias which won't be retyped, but yes `@` is shorter.